# Can I Increase the Number of Log Entries in Google App Engine? (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

Is it possible to increase the number of log "entries" that google app engine stores? I mean the entries that are available in the online dashboard under the "Logs" link.

I can roll my own logging system using the database, but it's not my preference, as using the built in logging module is easiest by far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting to increase the amount of history App Engine will store for logs. You could, however, run a local cron job to pull logs down from the server. appcfg.py will download the logs, eg.

```
appcfg.py request_logs appid/ appidlogs.txt
```

Docs are here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs

Comment: I'll log it in the database so it stays in the cloud, ty anyway though.